# The "edit" link in the tags page takes me to a different edit page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I tried editing the Wiki page for [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7), but when I click it, I am taken to the page for editing the Wiki page for [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce). I tried the same with [6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6), but in that case, I get a error 404 page.

Could not be the problem caused by the fact the tags contain only a number, and the software is interpreting it as a tag ID? In that case, the edit link is not understood to be for [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7), but for the tag with ID 7, which (in the database) is the ID for [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce). I checked other edit links, and the only ones for which I have a problem are [6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6) and [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7). I will try creating [5](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5) and see if I have the same problem for that tag.

[image: screenshot #1]

[image: screenshot #2]

If I hover the tag itself, and I click on the edit link that appears in the drop-down menu, I am taken to `https://drupal.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/425`; the other edit link, which takes me to the edit page for [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) is `https://drupal.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/7`. As you can see, the difference is just the number that appears as last item; this means that the code handling those URLs is not able to understand if it gets a tag name, or a tag ID. More correctly, the code that handles those URLs interprets the number passed as last component of the URL to be a tag ID, and interprets a string passed as last component of the path as tag name.

The only solution in the short term is not to use numbers as tag name.

[image: screenshot #3]

Comment: As I supposed, the problem is just with the tags containing numbers; if you try using the edit link for the "5" tag (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/5), you will get an error 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed this; it will be deployed shortly.